# Responsive design and margin-left

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I'm making a responsive site with 2 columns (DIVs) layout. I use `display:inline-block` to align the DIVs and use `margin-left` to separate DIV2 from DIV1.

DIV2 would show no content on mobile devices. When it has no content, it would still push DIV1 with `margin-left` value for some reason.

I expected it would be ignored altogether and DIV1 would be centred alone but it didn't go like this. `#div2:empty` is not an option as I tried it and it's not working because DIV2 is actually not empty; it has a script that shows content on mobile devices only, so `:empty` has no effect in this case.

I made a simple JS fiddle to demo the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/3rvGZ/

You will see that although DIV2 has no content, it would still push DIV1 to left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to deal with it would be to add metadata to your DOM, but it seems it is not an option.

The `margin-left` property is applied to empty elements.
But if you use

```
position: relative;
left: 20px;
```

on `DIV2`, this will only be taken into account if there is content in it.

If this can solve your issue, it seems simple enough.

Answer (score 1):

Unless it breaks your full design, which I expect is more complex, you can use `padding` instead of `margin`:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LcLk/3rvGZ/1/)

Comment: i tried it but still it pushes DIV1 exactly like margin. Try to replace padding with margin. Still not centred

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: none` in order to rip it completely out of the layout.

It might not be what you want but this will work.

Comment: i don't want to hide the element. I think it would be easier to remove it altogether.